# Update manager has managed to hang itself while updating (13.04 to 13.10)

Tags: 13.04, update-manager, 13.10

I was updating my Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10. All the packages were downloaded and were being installed, while all of a sudden the update manager window went dim.

I ran `ps -A` and I can see a process called `saucy` however, how can I get my update manager to restart? I am afraid that since my updates manager has already (and possibly) installed some of the packages, my installation might go kaput and I might have to start everything from zero.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

This is an especially serious problem, which also occurred in an earlier release, since it blocks a novice user's fix of the problem (no way to update). The hang also stops a user from logging out, risking a dangerous power down as a solution. (Don't ever do that -- you'll need to manually eliminate software list fragments from root or the GUI updater will never work again.) Although somewhat risky, you can drop to Terminal and use a KILL [process ID] command to dismiss the hung process (after using ps -ux to retrieve the process ID), then use apt-get update (and) upgrade in Terminal for future updates, until you're certain the GUI updater is repaired.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, I have the same problem, on two computers. The first box looks suspiciously like a new install.

The second one I was more careful, dropped to console, killed the updater. Then ran

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Don't know if it's safe to reboot now.

The update seems to hang near or at a kernel update, when doing a reboot there is an error shown with a file system access problem. Couldn't fix it using the repair console.

Greetings.

Edit: it was safe to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in 12.04.  had something lock a bunch of files/  I went through and removed all the locked files one by one using the

```
sudo rm
```

command for each locked file and ran

```
sudo apt-get -a
```

after each time, and each time had to remove a locked file.  eventually I got through about 8 locked files and had a run w/ grub asking me to create  missing file.  said yes.  then a reboot and a update and everything is cool.  pain in the ass problem.  look at my question about software center 4 more info

Comment: link of your question?